# Installing ffmpeg on CentOS 6.6

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to install ffmpeg,.. 
When I write comand:

```
git clone --depth 1 http://source.ffmpeg.org/git/ffmpeg.git
```

I got this error.. why??

> Initialized empty Git repository in
>   /root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/.git/ fatal: dumb http transport
>   does not support --depth

Installing from this source.. 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

Comment: This has been fixed on the wiki. The git repo URL was changed, but the `--depth` was not removed. Also, consider accepting Bret''s answer since it provides a working solution for the specific issue in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the "dumb" http protocol doesn't support using the --depth tag. You need to use `git://`:

```
git clone --depth 1 git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg
```

More information [here](https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days).

Comment: Thanks. But now I have another error. when write next command. Error looks this: -bash: .configure/: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right directory? I see a `configure` file in the root of the git project, but the output from your terminal is claiming it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, have done.. But very much warnings and deprecated functions.. Hope, it will work..

Comment: Do you have a specific requirement to build from source? You can use yum to install ffmpeg: https://chrisjean.com/install-ffmpeg-and-ffmpeg-php-on-centos-easily/

Comment: Have installed.. But missing ffprobe.. How to install it??